# Yodlee using OAuth or Stored Credentials

Tags: oauth, yodlee

I'm new to Yodlee, and it seems to me from their guidelines, that you need to sign in with the consumer's credentials every time I want to request their transactions. I wanted to know if there is an OAuth way of doing this, or any other way, without having to store the consumer's creds in my database? I don't want my users to have to log in every single time or whenever the session is timed-out.
Is this what Yodlee calls FastLink? If possible, please provide a sample code (Java). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**In short**- **No, it is not mandatory for you to store user's bank credentials in your data base.**

**Detailed:**

For your better understanding I am explaining the steps involved in detail for user login and credentials storing.

There are 3 steps involved.

**Step 1:** User come to your Application and your application validate it for e.g., they might register on day 1 and on day 2 they'll come to your application and login. You should be storing their login information to validate them. You can use this same credentials of user to register and login to Yodlee system.

**Step 2:** Yodlee requires bank name and its credentials of that particular user for aggregation, you can store these credentials at your end(Database) or need not to store(instead directly pass it on to Yodlee) and Yodlee will store it into their database for further processing i.e., refreshing and getting latest data and transactions details after login in on behalf of user. You can invoke Yodlee Fastlink wizard and allow user to search the particular Bank site and add an account. This will speed up the process of integration with Yodlee and also in this case user is entering his/her credentials directly to Yodlee.

**Step 3:** Yodlee will refresh the account for that particular user using the bank credentials saved in the Yodlee system and you can retrieve the data from Yodlee database using the user login credentials with which user has registered to your application(not bank credentials).

User has to login and refresh the sites which asks for MFA(Multi-Factor Authentication), coz it requires their interaction.

[Here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/FastLink_for_Aggregation) you'll find the details for Fastlink integration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer...But I'm really asking, for the case when  the user is not interfacing through the application...but rather 'offline' time...like once a day automatically. It seems to me that  in that case, I would have to store the credentials, correct?

Comment: I mean the Yodlee credentials, such as the user's Yodlee login and Yodlee's passwords.

Comment: Yes, you will need to store the Yodlee credential.

Comment: what's about security? If I need to send login/password to yodlee - I have security problem in the app